# Changing SegmentControl button label font size

Tags: ios4

I am new to Iphone developement.I want to create segment control with custom font size on buton label.Is there any way to do this in IPhone SDK 4?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

check the link:
http://matteocaldari.it/2010/05/a-uisegmentedcontrol-with-custom-color